# UICollectionView: change the layout on the fly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a requirement to create a view controller that behaves a lot like a webpage; if the user presses the button, the layout changes on-the-fly, and the press another button and it goes back to divisional layout. the first layout is like a table view, the second more like a collection view with a custom layout. is it possible to change a collection view layout on-the-fly?  Heretofore I have only set the layout  once and left it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the `-setCollectionViewLayout:animated:` method.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/setCollectionViewLayout:animated:

Comment: use of setCollectionViewLayout is  actually causing a bad access error

Comment: @moop that suggests you are not keeping a reference to the collectionview object around. are you storing it in a strong @property?

Comment: yes definitely  it is strong, as are the two layouts. the first layout is a flow layout and the second layout that causes a crash  when I try to switch to it is a custom layout.

Comment: Ugh... I found the problem. another programmer had used "hdr" instead of UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader.  still that  ought not result in a crash.